# Changing two div's with one ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, rss

I have a function on my project which allows users to set certain rss source as favourite.

I'm using codeigniter, and my view is something like that:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse">
   <h5><b> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span> Favorites </b></i></h5>
</a>

<ul class="list-unstyled collapse in" id="favorites">
   <?php foreach( $source as $fav ) :  if( $fav->favourite == 1 ) {?>
      <li>
         <a id="some_id">  <?php echo $fav->rss_title; ?></a>
      </li>
   <?php } endforeach; } ?>
</ul>

   <!-- all favorite links are placed in a left sidebar....in header, i have a div with different opperations... -->
   <div class="col-sm-12">               
      <?php if ( $isFavourite == 0 ) { ?>
          <li><h4><a class="addfav" id='just_id' href="#favorite">Add this Rss Source to Favourites</a></h4></li>
      <?php } else { ?>
          <li><h4><a class="removefav" id='just_id' href="#favorite">Remove this Rss Source from Favourites</a></h4></li>
      <?php } ?>

      // and other options ...
   </div>
```

Here is the script where i use ajax:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.addfav',function(){
        var id=this.id;

        $.ajax( {
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {id:id},
                    url: "<?php echo site_url('rssFeedReader/addFavorites'); ?>",
                    success: function(msg) 
                    {
                        $("#favorites").append(msg);
                    }
                })
    });
});
</script>
```

Everything is working fine, but i cannot do something...after i add to favourites the link( via 'append' ), I want to change the option in my header from 'Add this Rss Source to favourites' to 'Remove this rss Source to favourites'. I did this, but only work if i reload the page...I want to do this when i add the link with ajax....

How can i change the div which contain those options, in the same ajax call ? Can i do something after the line '$('#favorites').append(msg); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the option, do this:

```
$('.addfav').addClass('removefav').removeClass('addfav').text('Remove this Rss Source from Favourites');
```

after the

```
$("#favorites").append(msg);
```

line

This will transform

```
<a class="addfav" id='just_id' href="#favorite">Add this Rss Source to Favourites</a>
```

to

```
<a class="removefav" id='just_id' href="#favorite">Remove this Rss Source from Favourites</a>
```

and after you can obviously add listener to the object to add fucntionnalities.